# Development of the commissural fibers

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

Having a look at the corpus callosum one sees that the axons passing the corpus callosum (the  commissural fibers) connect mirror-symmetric counter regions of the cortex (roughly).

[image]

Is there a model that explains how the growing axons find their way to their far-away targets in this highly structured way?

(One possibility would be that the counter regions originally were close to each other but separated during brain development.)